# How to compile .obj files into final executable?

Tags: c++, blender, winapi

I have created a .obj model in Blender.

I am writing a screensaver, so, I can have only one file(.scr)?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at screen saver criteria, but I don't recall ever seeing a one file limitation. Time was that a screen saver was essentially just a renamed .exe - there were some optional API hooks if you wanted to connect to the standard config menus or something, but as I recall even that was optional. Where did you see the one file limitation that you're referring to?

Comment: @pikalek So, the user must install the software. Maybe that's what you are saying? I want that the user must be able to copy the screensaver to another computer.

Comment: I'm asking where you encountered the one file limitation because I don't think it is correct. I thought I recalled screen savers that dynamically load & display images slide show style, but I could be wrong. Since it's not easy to prove a negative, I'm asking where you encountered that particular requirement.

Comment: @Pikalek One file requirement is for easy handling of the .scr file plus no leakage of .obj files.

Comment: There's an almost infinite number of ways to embed data into an executable. At the most basic, you could convert the file to a byte array and define it in the executable itself.  The real question is what format you need the data in when the screensaver is running and how to recreate that format from [whatever mechanism you use to store the data]

Comment: @Basic I recall resource file is to be used. Thanks.

Comment: In c++ you can use the raw string literal to add the text of the obj file directly to the program R"(...)"  For obj files this may be all you need. The file then becomes a string literal for example `const char *obj_data = R("this is data with funky escape sequences ignored.")`

Comment: This is not a valid question for game dev since your question roughly translates to: How do I convert a Blender file to a Windows Executable then rename to `.scr`.